# Merging on different keys into one field in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-analysis, data-integration

I am inserting two excel files into pentaho.
Each excel file has multiple sheets.
For example I am merging asset data.

Each asset has a unique key.
When merging using a full outer join, because there are no matches on the keys, a new field is created called assetnum_1. Therefore I am left with two fields: assetnum and assetnum_1.

I do not want assetnum_1. 
I want all the data to be in assetnum.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: It will help a lot in understanding what you are doing if you could provide an example with sample data. Its really hard to get what you are trying here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join different aspects of an asset using a Merge-Join step, you will always find all the fields from all input streams in your resulting stream.  If fields don't have unique names, Kettle will solve the name conflict by adding an underscore followed by a collision count.  You can ignore those fields or use a Select-Values step to remove them midstream, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

if there are no matches, why not you append the data from both excel files. Use append step or simply out the output of the both excel sheets steps to select step. there structure have to be same for append to work though.